# Clearing a text file using FileStream on a file that is in use by another FileStream

Tags: c#, .net

```
/*Initialize FileStreams for both writing and reading*/
writeStream = new FileStream(logfilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
readStream = new FileStream(logfilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

/*Initialize the Writer and Reader*/
fileWrite = new StreamWriter(writeStream);
fileRead = new StreamReader(readStream);
```

So this is what I use to be able to constantly write and read to the same file. How can I clear the file without the need to close both streams temporarily, clear file, and reopen them again?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. You want to write whatever changes you have, and re-load the StreamReader with the updated text?

Comment: I'm using the displayed code to write and read a text file. At certain point during runtime I need to clear the file content. How am I able to do that in a neat and proper way, without having to close the already open streams?

Comment: Does `writeStream.SetLength(0)` achieve what you want? Note that this will still futz up the positions of the `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` instances on the file; I have no idea if they will continue to operate correctly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've already tried that, and it does not work

Comment: It doesn't work because you're using `FileMode.Append` in the `writeStream`. How about using `FileMode.Open` and seeking to the end manually? Note that this requirement (to seek) perfectly illustrates why truncating the file mid-stream without any reset is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The problem with using `FileMode.Open` is that it will overwrite any existing content when the FileStream is initialized

Comment: @pnda why wouldn't you want to close the opened file stream? Is this file shared between different users or processes? IMO if you're interested in a more dynamic read-write object, you might want to rethink the process a bit.

Comment: @SpaceSteak It's not the end of the world if I have to close the streams, I was just wondering if there was any way to avoid it for the purpose of neat looking code. Any recommendations to what i should look into instead that might solve my problem?

Comment: I mean `writeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)`, which will leave any existing content alone.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I couldn't quite get it working, but I'll just close streams to clear them, and look into a more dynamic way of doing it in the future. Thanks for the help!